# Create java method that only accepts non-abstract Class types

Tags: java, class, generics, abstract, signature

In Java, is it possible to create a method / a signature that accepts *all* non-abstract Class types?

Something a la this:

```
public Object getInstance(Class<? extends ConcreteClassSuperType> someNonAbstractClass){
  //some logic that can safely assume that the Class object is not an interface type nor an abstract class
}
```

where `ConcreteClassSuperType` is just a fictional type made up to illustrate my intend. Using `? extends Object`here does not solve the problem.

**Elaboration:** 
 In the case at hand the problem was a bit more specific in that my signature dit not have to accept **ALL** concrete classes but only those implementing some interface, i.e. I was trying to create a signature that accepts the Class type of a class that `implements MyInterface`. So one could fx pass `MyClass.class`, where `MyClass implements MyInterface`. Two problems occured:

1. The signature will also accept `MyInterface.class` (since the generics `Class<? extends MyInterface>` is not a strict upper bound)
2. One can pass the class type of another interface that `extends MyInterface`.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Can you explain why you need this? There may be another solution if you can show the bigger picture.

Comment: What is the problem with it accepting `MyInterface`? What exactly is the method supposed to do?

Comment: I think that you can perform a check directly inside the method and throw an exception if the check fails. You can easily determine if the given class is an interface or is abstract, I think. Something like: `if (clz == null || clz.isInterface() || Modifier.isAbstract(clz.getModifiers())) { throw new IllegalArgumentException();}`

Comment: Well, not anything super concrete, just that I was thinking about how one could go about creating some framework or library that made it possible/easy to create an annotation with an annotation member that referred to a method  - MyAnnotation(delegate=MyClass::myMethod) is not possible. One would have to pass either a String (in some customer format that includes FQCN and parameters) or perhaps using some Class (like the implementation of a SAM I was thinking). Somehow this brought me to above question. But thanks for the comments/answers.

Comment: Reflection. But only if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Because classes can have multiple parameters, I think it is easier first just to check if the class is concrete and then implement a means to instantiate it. Like,

```
public <T> boolean isConcrete(Class<T> c) {

    if (c.isInterface() || (c.getModifiers() & Modifier.ABSTRACT) == Modifier.ABSTRACT)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Sorry just noticed in another comment you could simplify this...

```
public <T> boolean isConcrete(Class<T> c) {

    if (c.isInterface() || Modifier.isAbstract(c.getModifiers()))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you can optimize this even more. Just negate the condition and return it